# GCC hide specific warning type

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

In writing an emulator, I am using a lot of various large unsigned constants, and, hence, on compilation receive a very large number of warnings of the form:

```
warning: this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90 [enabled by default]
```

making it difficult to debug the rest of the program. I understand that this can be suppressed with a pragma:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-W...."
```

But I am not sure which kind of warning this falls into and don't want to disable "-Wall" in case there are other more important warnings.

What is the smallest subset of warnings that can be disabled to remove this warning?

EDIT: As requested, one of the functions that trigger the message:

```
void NAND(unsigned int *to_return, unsigned int r1_value, unsigned int r2_value){
    unsigned int result = (r1_value & r2_value) ^ 4294967295;
    to_return[0] = result;
    to_return2] = 0;
}
```

Specifically, the 4294967295 constant.

This was compiled under:

```
gcc -O3 "C source\Hard Disk Version\CPU.c" -o CEmuTest.exe
```

on Windows (minGW).

Comment: Please provide a code example that triggers the message, gcc version and flags used to compile.

Comment: Compiled without warnings at all? You said it isn't: *and don't want to disable "-Wall" i* I think gcc compiles in C90 by default, so you are seeing this warning. Try compiling with -std=c99

Comment: You should be able to get rid of most warnings by suffixing the constants with "U" in order to tell the compiler you want them to be unsigned.

Comment: Don't suppress warnings, but fix your code! Warnings are not there to annoy, but to show problematic code.